# How to stop tabs from being recreated on each activity call

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an application that has an index page which has tabs for navigation. This page has multiple children pages being implemented as fragments.
[image]

Some of my children fragment views also have tabs in them for more navigation like below
[image]

The issue i am having is when i switch from one of these fragments to the other, and return to it.The tabs on that one are recreated like so
[image]
And i'm not sure how to solve this problem as it is my first time getting this serious with tabs.

Below is my code for the top-level-tab adapter

```
public class indexTabAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    private List<String> titleList;
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList;


    public indexTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragmentList, List<String> titleList)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
        this.titleList = titleList;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {

        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {

        return fragmentList.size();

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return titleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Below here is the code for the activity class managing the top-level-tabs

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index_page);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.indexViewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.indexTabs);

        prepareDataResource();

        indexTabAdapter ita = new indexTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragmentList,titleList);

        pager.setAdapter(ita);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

        ita.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }

    private void prepareDataResource()
    {
        fragmentList.add(new dash());
        titleList.add("Dash");

        fragmentList.add(new AcademicCalender());
        titleList.add("Calender");

        fragmentList.add(new IncidentReport());
        titleList.add("Incident Report");

        fragmentList.add(new Profile());
        titleList.add("Profile");

        fragmentList.add(new Pta());
        titleList.add("PTA");

        fragmentList.add(new timeTable());
        titleList.add("Time Table");

        fragmentList.add(new Results());
        titleList.add("Results");
    }
```

Lastly, this is the code for the lower-level-tab that keeps repeating

```
public class Profile extends Fragment
{
    private List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ViewPager pager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    public Profile()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_view_activity,container,false);


        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.profileViewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.profileTabs);

        prepareDataResource();

        profileTabsAdapter rta = new  profileTabsAdapter(getFragmentManager(),fragmentList,titleList);

        pager.setAdapter(rta);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

        return view;
    }

    private void prepareDataResource()
    {
        fragmentList.add(new index());
        titleList.add("Home");

        fragmentList.add(new immunization());
        titleList.add("Immunization");

        fragmentList.add(new information());
        titleList.add("Information");

        fragmentList.add(new records());
        titleList.add("Health Records");


    }
}
```

Comment: Add your code for that fragment initialisation, and which adapter you're using for the top-level tabs ViewPager.

Comment: Please update question with your code as it will help community members to assist you.

Comment: Something wrong with your ArrayList. Its getting initialise again.

Comment: @RamithDR The code has been added now

Comment: Please let me know if you require more information

Comment: What is the problem with the recreation? Keeping so many tabs (a.k.a. view) in memory will be a big trouble for your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FragmentPagerAdapter` instances your fragment once. So if you instantiate your list when declaring it as a field, it will always retain that same list, thus adding elements when the Fragment's `onCreateView` is called.

To avoid this, declare and instantiate both lists like this:

```
public class Profile extends Fragment {
    private List<String> titleList;
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //your code for views initialization

        //init the lists here!
        titleList = new ArrayList<>();
        fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        prepareDataResource();

        //your adapter set up code

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're working with `ViewPager`, try calling `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfTabs)`. I'm not a hundred percent sure this will work, but it won't hurt to try.

From the official Android documentation:

> ```
> setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)
> ```
>
> > Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
> >     current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.